# Binding data in listview itemtemplate using style

Tags: c#, windows, listview, data-binding, windows-store-apps

I cannot bind my sample data to textblocks in stackpanel, which I defined in resources. I think that I use style in wrong way, because I receive toString() method instead of class binded fields.

That's my resources with defined style:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VirtualizingStackPanelTemplate">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ListView x:Key="ListBoxTemplate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<ListBoxItem Background="DarkOrchid" Margin="1,1, 5,5" Height="400" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">-->
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Desc}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                <!--</ListBoxItem>-->
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Here is my method in which i add listview programatically:

```
        long rowCount = ContentGridFullView.RowDefinitions.LongCount();
        if (rowCount > 8) return;
        var c1 = new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
        ContentGridFullView.RowDefinitions.Add(c1);
        rowCount = ContentGridFullView.RowDefinitions.LongCount();
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock {Text = "TEXTBLOCK ITEM = " + (rowCount - 1), FontSize = 40};
        Viewbox vb = new Viewbox { Child = tb };
        if (rowCount > 8) return;
        Grid.SetRow(vb, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount-1));
        Grid.SetColumn(vb, 1);
        ListView lb = new ListView();
       lb.Style = Resources["ListBoxTemplate"] as Style;
       lb.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate) Resources["VirtualizingStackPanelTemplate"];
       var products = new ObservableCollection<Product>() { new Product("ASDASDSADAS", "VCBVCBVCBVCBC"), new Product("ASDASDSADAS", "VCBVCBVCBVCBC"), new Product("ASDASDSADAS", "VCBVCBVCBVCBC"), new Product("ASDASDSADAS", "VCBVCBVCBVCBC") };
       lb.ItemsSource = products;
       ContentGridFullView.Children.Add(lb);
       ContentGridFullView.Children.Add(vb);
       Grid.SetRow(lb, Convert.ToInt32(rowCount - 1));
       Grid.SetColumn(lb, 2);
```

And my short class that I want to bind:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public Product(string title, string desc)
    {
        Title = title;
        Desc = desc;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I see that message instead of Title and Desc";
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code? Thank you.

Comment: Firstly why do you want to ListView  in the usercontrol.resources? Looks like your using the code behind to setup the data is that right? If your using the code behind, your usercontrol should be able to know the data is present in the code behind itself. You should use : DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=x}" where x is the name of the observable collection. You must look into the MVVM design pattern and your code becomes much more organized and you'll love it.

Comment: I'm creating collections & listviews dynamically in my code (tap event in button creates new listview and it's collection). I want to have one style of all created listviews. I cannot bind collection to listview, because I don't have any listview created in xaml. Is there any working way to create listviews and it's list programatically and set the same style of all created lists?

Answer (score 0):

Create your Observable collection as a property (getter/setter):

```
ObservableCollection<Product> _products;
public ObservableCollection<Product> products
{
    get{return  _products;}
    set
    {
        _products=value;
        PropertyChanged("products");
    }
}
```

The property changed event will be need to indicate that the collection has changed,its needed when your using ObservableCollection. You'll need to read more about it.You can add items to the products collection by using :

```
        products.Add(Product_object)
```

And your xaml code will have the itemsSource as follows:

```
<ListView x:Key="ListBoxTemplate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding products}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--<ListBoxItem Background="DarkOrchid" Margin="1,1, 5,5" Height="400" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">-->
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Desc}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            <!--</ListBoxItem>-->
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The following statement is important in your xaml code so that your xaml code will know where to look for the data.

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=x}
```

First try and create a static list and check if data is getting initialized properly and then you can try creating listviews dynamically. But the code above will be the same thing you will have to do create dynamic listviews.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work in my app. Listview is empty.

Comment: does your class extend INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes. Btw I cannot use one-arg method PropertyChanged.